# PHP PDO MYSQL/MARIADB How to query a view? (view not found error)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, view

I have a view in a MariaDB and a simple PDO query to select all data.

Working with regular tables, there are no issues at all. The only issue I have is that as soon as I use a VIEW, I get the error that the view does not exist.

[826]::sqlstate[42s02]: base table or view not found: 1146 table 'kafexxxx_diner.reservationsxmonth' doesn't exist

::select reservationsxmonth.property,reservationsxmonth.period,reservationsxmonth.total from reservationsxmonth limit 0, 10000

It doesn't look like a rights issue as the statement performs fine in phpMyAdmin.

The question is, can I use PDO to access views, and how to do it? Does the PDO connection require certain options?

```
     $pdo='mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=kafexxxx_diner;port=3306;charset=utf8';
     $this->connection = new PDO($pdo, $this->userid, $this->password, $options);
     $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: PDO does not need anything special to access views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works without a problem, so you should check for typos or check in your database, if the view was created

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM view_name");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['name']."<br />\n";
}
```

See [example](https://phpize.online/?phpses=1f2ff8c3bc26b01fefebe0bfdc5a057d&sqlses=d1651d3a0b025bafc9a15b4e2d0ee955&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: There are no typos as the statement works fine in adminer or phpMyAdmin. Could it be that this is a pdo driver issue? Some incompatibiltiy between MySQL and MariaDB? Your sample is almost the same as mine.
$sth=$dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `reservationsxmonth` LIMIT 50');
// fetch all rows into array, by default PDO::FETCH_BOTH is used
$rows = $sth->fetchAll();

// iterate over array by index and by name
foreach($rows as $row) {

    printf("$row[0] $row[1] $row[2]\n");
 
}

Comment: no you don't need any options as shown in the example, when my sql says it has no view with that name, then this is always true. Usually you are connected to different servers. you can run `SHOW FULL TABLES IN database_name WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';`to see which voews you have on that server.

Comment: No, found it, the server was configured to be case sensitive. Pffff. Thank you for your answer.